# Azure CDN "looses" requests

Tags: caching, configuration, azure-cdn

We're using Azure CDN (Verizon Standard) to serve images to ecommerce sites, however, we're experiencing unreasonable amount of loads from origin, images which should've been cached in the CDN is requested again multiple times.

Images seems to stay in the cache if they're requested very frequently (setting up a pingdom page speed test doesn't show the problem, it's executing every 30 minutes).

Additionally, if I request an image (using the browser), the scaled image is requested from the origin and delivered, but the second request doesn't return a cached file from the CDN but origin is called again. The third request returns from the CDN.

The origin is a web app which scales and delivers the requested images. All requests for images have the following headers which might affect caching:

`cache-control: max-age=31536000, s-maxage=31536000`

`ETag: e7bac8d5-3433-4ce3-9b09-49412ac43c12?cache=Always&maxheight=3200&maxwidth=3200&width=406&quality=85`

Since we want the CDN to cache the scaled image, Azure CDN Endpoint is configured to cache every unique url and the caching behaviour is "Set if missing" (although all responses have the headers above).

Using the same origin with AWS Cloudfront works perfectly (but since we have everything else in Azure, it would be nice to make it work). I haven't been able to find if there's any limit or constraints for the ETag but since it works with AWS it seems like I'm missing something related to either Azure or Verizon.

Comment: Any breakthrough on this? We're experiencing the same problem. Our images are set up to never expire, so ideally the CDN should come and get them only once.
Of course a CDN is not a single server instance, so I can expect a URL to be hit multiple times (e.g. POP servers being added / replaced from time to time), but in practice we see about 500 to 1000 requests a minute showing up on our server. This looks way too much to me, so I'm wondering if there's a magic setting we're missing here.